# Apex Trigger on Attachment object not being fired

Tags: apex, trigger, attachment

I wrote this apex trigger for Attachment sObject following the answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/247175/62146). The trigger basically counts the total number of attachments for a record of type `Assignment__c` and updates the field `Count_Attachment__c`. But the trigger doesn't seem to be firing when I add a pdf file to the `Notes and Attachments` section in a record of custom object type `Assignment__c`. The `Count_Attachment__c` field isn't updated and I don't see anything in the logs in developer console. I'd googled and found an old issue with triggers on attachment object dating back to 2010. Is it still an issue?

```
trigger count_attachements on Attachment (after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {
    Set<Id> parentIdsSet = new Set<Id>(); //stores the parentids linked with modified attachments
    List<Attachment> attachmentList = new List<Attachment>(); //stores the list of modified attachments

    if (Trigger.new != null) {
        attachmentList.addAll(Trigger.new);
    } else if (Trigger.old != null){
        attachmentList.addAll(Trigger.old);
    }

    for (Attachment at: attachmentList) {
        parentIdsSet.add(at.ParentId);
    }

    parentIdsSet.remove(null);

    //stores mapping parentIds to total attachment count for that id
    Map<Id, Integer> objecttIdToAttachmentCount = new Map<Id, Integer>();

    for(AggregateResult ar: [SELECT count(Id) attachmentCount, parentId FROM Attachment WHERE parentId IN :parentIdsSet GROUP BY parentId]) {
        Id objId = (Id)ar.get('parentId');
        Integer count = (Integer)ar.get('attachmentCount');

        count = count == null ? 0 : count;
        objecttIdToAttachmentCount.put(objId, count);
    }

    //for cases where parentid's last attachment is deleted as the above SOQL query wont include the deleted attachments
    for(Id parentId: parentIdsSet) {
        if(!objecttIdToAttachmentCount.containsKey(parentId)) {
            objecttIdToAttachmentCount.put(parentId, 0);
        }
    }

    // not necessary but useful if multiple object types in the parent list    
    Map<String, String> sobjectNameToTargetField = new Map<String, String> {
        'Assignement__c' => 'Count_Attachment__c'
    };

    List<SObject> parentRecordsToUpdate = new List<SObject>();

    for (Id parentId: objecttIdToAttachmentCount.keySet()) {
        SObjectType currentType = parentId.getSObjectType();

        if(!sobjectNameToTargetField.containsKey(currentType.getDescribe().getName())) {
            continue;
        }

        SObject parent = currentType.newSObject();
        parent.put(sobjectNameToTargetField.get(currentType.getDescribe().getName()), objecttIdToAttachmentCount.get(parentId));

        parentRecordsToUpdate.add(parent);
    }

    parentRecordsToUpdate.sort();
    update parentRecordsToUpdate;

}
```

Comment: Highly recommend using a tool for declarative rollups like dlrs. No need to write your own.

Comment: Is the file being added as a File (ContentDocument) or an Attachment?

Comment: @NickCook I'm adding it as an attachment in the 'Notes and Attachments' section

Comment: Are you using Lightning Experience? If so, Salesforce is creating Content objects, not Attachments, which are the older Classic type of file attachment.

Comment: @DavidReed Yes. So do you mean I should be using Content object to attach files to a record?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Sorry what is dlrs? Link to any source so that I can read on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trigger is not executing because, as you mention in comments, you're using Lightning Experience. In Lightning Experience, files are attached using the Content system, which creates `ContentDocument`, `ContentVersion`, and `ContentDocumentLink` records. The `ContentDocumentLink` associates a record to its parent. No `Attachment` is created in Lightning Experience.

You'll need to write your trigger against [`ContentDocumentLink`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm). I'd suggest getting started by reading through the SOAP API reference linked above. There are some interesting restrictions around how this object works, especially as to how you can perform queries against it.

Comment: Thanks for this info. I created an apex trigger for the ContentDocumentLink which is set to trigger after insert, after update, after delete and after undelete but the trigger only gets fired after insert but not after update or after delete. Though the documentation you linked above says that The ContentDocumentLink object supports triggers before and after these operations: insert, update, delete. Could you help?

Comment: Hi Aanchal, my guess is that what you're seeing is the trigger fires only on changes to the *link object*. It won't fire on changes to the attached file itself.

Comment: Ok I get it now. I found a discussion on the same topic and guess I'll have to write another trigger for the ContentDocument. So is it the 'ParentId' field that stores the Id of the parent record? The field description of the parentId in the docs is a bit confusing.

Comment: On ContentDocumentLink, it is LinkedEntityId. Remember also that ContentVersion is the object that actually is created when a new file version is added. There's a lot of complexity there so the best route will depend on exactly what you are aiming to do.

Comment: My goal is simply to display the total attachment counts in each assignment(custom object) records. Since, the attachment trigger won't work, I was expecting to write the whole logic in a single trigger for ContentDocumentLink, but I've realized I can't do that. I also noticed that apex trigger on ContentDocument object gets triggers on insert, update and delete but I dont know which field I should use to get the  Id of the parent record.

Comment: Aanchal, I think you only need a trigger on ContentDocumentLink to count the total attachments, since you are not concerned with the *contents* of the attachment.

Comment: But the trigger on ContentDocumentLink only works for insert action and not on the actions 'update' and 'delete'. Any help on this?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that needs to be verified

1. Please check if the API name of Assignment object is Assignement__c and not Assignment__c
2. You need to set the ID attribute for the records which needs to be updated, without which you won't be able to update the record. Ideally, it should give you an exception unless you are catching that exception.

   ```
   SObject parent = currentType.newSObject(parentId);
   //SObject parent = currentType.newSObject();
   //parent.put('Id', parentId); //you can use this if you are using parameter less method to construct your object 
   parent.put(sobjectNameToTargetField.get(currentType.getDescribe().getName()), objecttIdToAttachmentCount.get(parentId));
   parentRecordsToUpdate.add(parent);
   ```

Comment: I know I did a spelling error here. But 'Assignement__c' is the correct API name of the Assignment object.

Comment: Also, event if this error had been the cause of the issue, I'm sure I would have been able to see something is the logs.

Comment: @Aanchal, I updated the answer, you missed to set the ID for the records that needs to be updated.

Comment: Oh yes. I forgot to set the parentId as parameter. instead of the newSObject() I was supposed to use the newInstance() but I keep gettig the error that the functio doesn't exist.

Comment: We don't have newInstance() method on sObjectType class, instead you can use other overloaded method, newSObject(ID) which takes ID as a parameter. I updated the answer, hope that helps !

Comment: My major issue is that I can't even see any logs related to this trigger when I attach a file in an 'Assignment__c' type record. I attach the files under the section 'Notes and Attachment'.

Comment: Hi Aanchal, you can see the logs in the same debug log which gets generated when you attach a file to notes & attachment section. Your log name would be /p/attach/NoteAttach. And in order to see your logs, you will need to add system.debug statements in your code.  Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88636/discussion-between-aanchal-adhikari-and-vijay-ganji).